# mpi4py Bcast() deadlock

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, mpi4py

I am trying to use Bcast() to broadcast at every step a numpy array that changes recursively. My code looks like this:

```
gn_forecast =np.empty((4*p,1), dtype=np.float64)
if (rank == 0):
    gn_forecast = np.zeros((4*p,1), dtype=np.float64)

if (rank ==0):
    count = 0
    for l in range(p):
        for k in range(4):
            gn_forecast[count] = (history[k][len(history[k])-l-1])
            count+=1

comm.Bcast(gn_forecast,root=0)
```

When I use the Bcast(). I hit on a deadlock probably as I got no errors and the script does not finish.
Can anyone see why?

Comment: Your code is not complete. In order to get some help, most people will expect  [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Moreover, your MPI implementation (OpenMPI, MPICH, ...) and version could help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `Bcast` properly. As first argument, you should provide a list with the numpy array as first element (`gn_forecast`), and the MPI type as second element. In your case, it is `MPI.DOUBLE`.

I have simplified the serial part of your code and the following is working on my side:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.rank
p=1

gn_forecast =np.empty((4*p,1), dtype=np.float64)
if (rank == 0):
    gn_forecast = np.ones((4*p,1), dtype=np.float64)*5.0

print("Rank: ", rank, ". gn_forecast is:\n", gn_forecast)
comm.Bcast( [gn_forecast, MPI.DOUBLE] ,root=0)
print("Rank: ", rank, ". gn_forecast is:\n", gn_forecast)
```